# How to map object-oriented structure to form fields?

Tags: java, xml, oop, groovy, pdfbox

I've created an object oriented structure with classes like Header, Address, Subject, DetailedItem. Each of these classes has got fields of various types:

```
public class Address {
    private String countryCode;
    private String voivodeship;
    private String county;
    private String community;

    // more fields, constructors, getters & setters..
}
```

or

```
public class Subject1 {
    private NonPhysicalPerson nonPhysicalPerson;
    private PhysicalPerson physicalPerson;

    // more fields, constructors, getters & setters..
}
```

and I've got a PDF form, with sth. around 100 fields. Each field is represented by ID:

- For Header section of PDF: h1, h2, ..., hn
- For Subject1 section of PDF: s1, s2, ..., sn
- For Subject2 section of PDF: t1, t2, ..., tn
- For Details section of PDF: d1, d2, ..., dn

I've got one problem with this. I've no idea how to map that fields to form IDs. I just want to avoid doing sth like (I've got special class field with data for every form field - I mean for 'h4' I've to use `getOne()`, for 'h5' `getSthDifferent()` etc.):

```
    List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();
    for (PDField field : fields) {
        String fieldName = field.getFullyQualifiedName();

        // branching like that would be terrible
        if (fieldName.equals("h1")) {
            field.setValue(header.getFormCode());
        } else if (fieldName.equals("h2")) {
            field.setValue(header.getFormVariant());
        } else if (fieldName.equals(...)) {
            // etc...
        } else if (fieldName.equals("d43")) {
            field.setValue(detailedItem.getDetailsMap().getKey("d43"));
        } 
    }
```

Is there any way to do it elegantly (any design-pattern or just tricky idea)?
I'm using Java, Groovy + PDFBox.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT (MY SOLUTION)**

Every class that is object-oriented representation of specified form section, now implements interface with `List<String> getData()` method. I'm adding class fields values to `List<String> data` and then addAll in top level class `List<String> data` for every section:

```
    data.addAll(header.getData());
    data.addAll(subject1.getData());
    data.addAll(subject2.getData());
    data.addAll(details.getData());
```

Order of fields is always constant in my case, so I'm able to fill data correctly just in one `for` loop. I think my implementation is flexible enough for my purposes. Additionally for loop looks like:

```
    for (int i = range.getStartIndex(); i < range.getEndIndex(); i++) {
        fields.get(i).setValue(data.get(i));
    }
```

where `startIndex` and `endIndex` are bounds of every section, so I'm able to choose sections prepared to fill.

Maybe my solution is not the cleanest option (+ we've to keep performance in mind, so **optimization will be necessary in the future**), but it's easy to modify. I hope it'd help someone.

Comment: concerning your solution: performance is not your problem, maintainability will be. If someone ever edits the pdf, the order of the AcroForm fields may change as a side effect. As a consequence you might have to reshuffle your `data` list. And if that happens multiple times, no-one will understand the hassle...

Comment: You're right (accurate observation), but I know frequency of that form changes (~ once per every 2 years), so it's not a problem in my case.

Comment: Every other year... oh well... then the issue might be differently: probably no one then remembers how to adapt the code... ;)

Comment: You're totally right again! I put there a nice and short JavaDoc with simple "user manual". I'd rather do it better, but.. **deadline**. Hope to get some time for refactoring. If yes - I'll post newer and cleaner solution here.

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't treat PDFField as a stupid object / collection of data

You have a direct association between the `field's name` and `the way you set the field's value`, this might indicate that there is a problem with your architecture.

The class that incapsulates the `switch` (let's call it class `A`) is too concerned about your `PDFField` object (it's asking too many questions about the field's internal data and mutates it's state).

You treat `PDFField` as a collection of data, not as an object (that knows how to work with his internal state) <-- I can't help you with this problem, because I can't **see** the overall code source.

#### Possible solution to avoid that switch

You can use a dictionary as `Dictionary<String, Consumer<PDFFiled>>` and
 `(key, value) = ("string", (field) -> field.setValue(/*value*/))`

... and you ask for the consumer using the key (field's name) and with the consumer you accept the filed. `fields.forEach(field -> dict.get(filed.getName()).accept(filed)`

This is **NOT a good solution**! You'll avoid the switch, but the code will still be hard to maintain (hard to extend, hard to change etc).

#### Other Notes

In your case you can't use a design pattern as `Strategy`, `Chain of responsibility`, `Decorator`, `Factory` because you can't create 100+ classes just to incapsulate a line of code that changes the field's value.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but there is one important detail - that form is created for structure, not the other way around. It's good for my requirements, but there were some problems with 1:1 relation (as can u see). I added my solution to original question.